# The jQuery treeview plugin doesn't work within a jQuery accordion plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, accordion

I am currently using the jQuery accordion plugin, and I need to use the treeview plugin within the accordion. However this doesn't work, and it seems to be a known problem (try googling "jquery accordion treeview").

Are there any plugins that might replace treeview but provide me with a similar flexible tree-like navigation behaviour? (and also works within an accordion)

Comment: The best advice that I can offer in this situation is to get the full source for both plugins, get yourself firebug, set some breakpoints and start to debug to find where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind straying away from jquery for a moment,
you can try the tree-view from YUI.   You can safely mix and mach YUI with Jquery and it is also cross browser compatible.  The Yahoo Treeview information can be found here
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/

and there are a bunch of examples and on line demos here
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/index.html

Comment: Hi and thanks! However, I am seeing the exact same problem with the YUI treeview, as I tried it now. It behaves slightly different though, but is still highly dysfunctional.

Comment: Strike that, the YUI treeview works perfectly (: There was a slight css problem, but I got around it. Thanks!